# Java TimeStamp in different Format

Tags: java, date, jdbc, timestamp

I want to insert the Java TimeStamp into database table.

I am using the following statement:

```
pstmt.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
```

Its returning timestamp in this format

> `2014-09-12 14:27:11.263`

But the table only accepts data in the following format :

> `03-SEP-14 02.25.12.940000000 PM`

How to format the timestamp to this format?

Comment: It is `Timestamp` not `varchar` in fixed format,  so you don't need to format it, you just pass it as `Timestamp`

Comment: that is automatically handled by `PreparedStatment`

Comment: I want to pass the getTime() in DD-MON-YY HH.MM.SS format.

Comment: No you don't need to set the format of the date. Just pass the `Timestamp` object that is formed by milli-seconds got from `Date` object. Are you getting any Exception?

Comment: yes.. I have a table with 5 columns. First two are number, next is varchar2, next is char and last is timestamp. This is what I have in java code

`pstmt.setInt(1,intval1);
     pstmt.setInt(2, intval2);
     pstmt.setString(3, Stringval1);
     pstmt.setString(4, String.valueOf(charval));
     pstmt.setTimestamp(5,new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));`

I am getting the following error :
`ROOT SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`

Comment: Are you specifying all fields in the insert SQL in the order you set the in prepared statement?